# XSL for-each with sort

Tags: xml, xslt

It's been a while since I've dealt with XPath/XSL and I cannot seem to get 'sort' to work with a loop. With the example XML below, what I would like to do is sort based on the value of the 'TextValue' attribute where 'ExternalName' is 'isDefault'. So with the example XML and the first sort attempt, I'm expecting to iterate in the order of 'Blah2' then 'Blah1'. I have tried many variations and even tried sorting just off an element value, but can't seem to get any sort to work. Any help would be appreciated.

XML:

```
<ProductsExport>
    <ProductExport>
        <ProductId>1</ProductId>
        <ProductCode>Blah1</ProductCode>
        <ProductType>Apparel</ProductType>
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute TextValue="Yes" ExternalName="Something" LocaleID="Default"/>
            <Attribute TextValue="No" ExternalName="isDefault" LocaleID="Default"/>
        </Attributes>
    </ProductExport>
    <ProductExport>
        <ProductId>2</ProductId>
        <ProductCode>Blah2</ProductCode>
        <ProductType>Apparel</ProductType>
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute TextValue="Yes" ExternalName="Something" LocaleID="Default"/>
            <Attribute TextValue="Yes" ExternalName="isDefault" LocaleID="Default"/>
        </Attributes>
    </ProductExport>
</ProductsExport>
```

Sort Attempts:

```
<xsl:sort select="./Attributes/Attribute[@ExternalName = 'isDefault']/@TextValue" order="descending"/>
<xsl:sort select="/ProductsExport/ProductExport/@ProductCode"/>
<xsl:sort select="@ProductCode"/>
<xsl:sort select="./ProductsExport/ProductExport/@ProductCode"/>
```

Comment: where is the rest of your template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPaths are trying to access `ProductCode` as an attribute `@ProductCode` ... it is an element.

```
<xsl:template  match="/">
  <ProductsExport>
  <xsl:for-each select="ProductsExport/ProductExport">
    <xsl:sort select="./Attributes/Attribute[@ExternalName = 'isDefault']/@TextValue" 
              order="descending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="./ProductCode"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </ProductsExport>
</xsl:template>
```

... Example Input ...

```
<ProductsExport>
  <ProductExport>
    <ProductCode>BlahD</ProductCode>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute TextValue="Yes" ExternalName="isDefault" LocaleID="Default"/>
    </Attributes>
  </ProductExport>
  <ProductExport>
    <ProductCode>BlahC</ProductCode>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute TextValue="No" ExternalName="isDefault" LocaleID="Default"/>
    </Attributes>
  </ProductExport>
  <ProductExport>
    <ProductCode>BlahB</ProductCode>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute TextValue="Yes" ExternalName="isDefault" LocaleID="Default"/>
    </Attributes>
  </ProductExport>
  <ProductExport>
    <ProductCode>BlahA</ProductCode>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute TextValue="No" ExternalName="isDefault" LocaleID="Default"/>
    </Attributes>
  </ProductExport>
</ProductsExport>
```

... Example Output ...

```
<ProductsExport>
  <ProductExport>
    <ProductCode>BlahB</ProductCode>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute TextValue="Yes" ExternalName="isDefault" LocaleID="Default" />
    </Attributes>
  </ProductExport>
  <ProductExport>
    <ProductCode>BlahD</ProductCode>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute TextValue="Yes" ExternalName="isDefault" LocaleID="Default" />
    </Attributes>
  </ProductExport>
  <ProductExport>
    <ProductCode>BlahA</ProductCode>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute TextValue="No" ExternalName="isDefault" LocaleID="Default" />
    </Attributes>
  </ProductExport>
  <ProductExport>
    <ProductCode>BlahC</ProductCode>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute TextValue="No" ExternalName="isDefault" LocaleID="Default" />
    </Attributes>
  </ProductExport>
</ProductsExport>
```

Comment: I apologize on my delay on accepting. I got pulled onto other things. So it looks like the sort I was attempting was correct, but something in the full XSL is causing it to behave unexpectedly, which we'll be looking at in the next few days. Thanks for your complete answer with example input/output.